# RecyclerView onItemClickListener and View.onClickListener inside adapter

Tags: java, android, xml

i'm developing a simple File Manager. This File Manager is inside a Fragment and, obviously, it use a RecyclerView to show folders and files. The layout that manage the row of list is composed by: 1 ImageView, 1 TextView (to show folder/file name) and one ImageView to select options (such as: rename, delete, etc.).

To manage click on RecyclerView i implemented a custom OnItemClickListener interface. The code is:

```
public class OnRecyclerItemClickListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {  

    GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    OnItemClickListener listener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public OnRecyclerItemClickListener(Context context, OnItemClickListener listener) {
       this.listener = listener;

       gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
               return true;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent e) {
        View childView = view.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
        if(childView != null && listener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
            ((OnItemClickListener) listener).onItemClick(childView, view.getChildAdapterPosition(childView));
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }
}
```

So, in the Fragment:

```
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new OnRecyclerItemClickListener(activity, new OnRecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub                  

        }
    }));
```

All works fine but now i have a problem: to manage the options when the user click on ImageView don't work properly because the RecyclerView.OnItemClickListener win on imageView.setOnClickListener. When the user click on the ImageView a PopupMenu is showed BUT always disappear because occur simultaneously RecyclerView.OnItemClickListener AND ImageView.OnClickListener. The first win to the second. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your click functionality to being handled within the `ViewHolder` you could then choose where to place your click listener. Doing this will allow you to place a clickable view inside your layout with the clickable `ImageView` being over the top of that. Below is a short example of doing this. You will need to fill in the gaps, as well as setting up the `Interface` properly. Let me know if you need any more help.

```
public interface ViewHolderListener {
    void itemClicked(int position);
    void imageClicked(int position);
}

public void fillView(ViewHolderItem item) {
        clickableView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
                viewHolderListener.itemClicked(getAdapterPosition());
    });

        yourImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener {
            viewHolderListener.imageClicked(getAdapterPosition());
    });
}
```

Comment: You're right but i need to manage also: SearchView function (declared inside the Fragment), onBackPressed (when the user presso on back button file manager come back to the previous path). How can i do this inside Adapter?

Comment: I don't understand your second question. Could you clarify? What is your SearchView function, and what is your query with onBackPressed? I can't see anything in your question about these methods.

Comment: The app that i'm developing is a File Manager. When the user click on a Folder it need also to be back to the previous folder, so i need to manage the onBackPressed event. How can i do this inside the Adapter? Second question: in the Fragment, in the Toolbar, i have a SearchView to search file. How can i implement in an Adapte?

Comment: You'll have to capture the back press by overriding `onBackPress` in your `Activity` and then calling a method inside your `Adapter` telling it that the user has requested a back press. 

With the search view it depends what you're asking, how to implement a search view inside your `Toolbar`, or how to register a search click in one of your items?

Answer (score 0):

At First you need to understand that the whole view will be come under Recycler View (Imageview +textview ). Now If you want to have two separate events for both Recycler view and ImageView click the ideal way should be you write them off in Adapter class of the Recyler view rather than creating an interface.

In the adapter class you write the onclick listener of the recycler view itself. like:

view.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
onClick){}
}

and for ImageView you write something like

imageview.setonClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
onClick){
// This code will not call --View.onClick of your Recycler View--}
}

It is the only way that both can operate separately.